# Is it possible to use custom where clauses like calling functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

I want to create a custom where clause, like calling a function, without using raw queries in prisma, i was wondering if there is a way to achieve this in prisma object.

For example: I want to query objects based on their distance to given location.

My Location table looks like this. (If necessary, i can merge 2 into single column)

| Id | Longitude | Latitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30.000 | 10.000 |
| 2 | 40.000 | 20.000 |
| 3 | 25.000 | 15.000 |

Lets say given location is lat 15.00 and long 10.00, and the distance is 1000 km. I only want to get objects in distance.

Normally this is achievable via postgis, but i have to turn this into prisma raw query which i am trying to avoid, because the example i gave is a simplication and the query itself is quite long with lots of relations, orders, selects etc.

This could be also possible with extensions like geolib; where i could just do query and via javascript, filter out results that doesnt fit distance; but the problem then; is i am doing pagination in the query and that would break pagination.

Is it possible to get at least the latitude value like;

```
where : {
   latitude : {
      lt: (val) => calculateMaxLat(val)
    }
}
```

Does anyone have idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't (currently) a way to use PostGIS in Prisma without writing a raw query. I've run into exactly the same use case as you, and I needed to manually enable the extension and write some raw queries to pull it off.

Prisma is adding support for native database extensions soon, which should help this issue greatly: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/enable-native-database-functions